# How to load Sharepoint feeds

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, rss

I am new to the Java script and JQuery world. I am writing a java script which will extract the RSS feeds from the news sites. for that I am using the Google API and below is the code:

```
var GetFeeds = function(URI)
{   
    var url=document.location.protocol + '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=1000&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent(URI);
    return $.get(url, {count:5}, null, 'JSON');
}
```

This is working for all the standard news websites but doesn't working for the share point. Please let me know how can I load the share point feeds or if I could load the response xml itself will be helpful.

Comment: If you are starting sharepoint you will ask a lot of quesiton. I recommend you to ask them on sharepoint.stackexchange

Comment: I am not more concerned about the Share point. Basically more interested to extract the feeds from Share Point.

Comment: Ok, anyway to get xml/json data you usually use `$.ajax`. So take a look on that. Here's the doc: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/